# Override Parent Hover

Tags: css

I am not sure how to disable the hover effect.  I'm using a navigation element from http://ink.sapo.pt/ plust my own custom css.  Everything is fine, meaning I'm able to get the border like I want and hover effect on the border (border turns from grey to red when I hover over Home).  But it is still underlining the text itself and I don't want that happening in my nav specifically.

```
        <nav className="ink-navigation">
            <ul className="menu horizontal">
                <li><a href="#"><span className="grey-dark bold underline-grey">Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span className="grey-dark bold underline-yellow">About</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Before hover:

[image]

After Hover:

[image]

The reason it's underlining during hover is because I have this in my .less:

```
@red: #C23033;

a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.underline-grey {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid @grey-xdark;
}

.underline-grey:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid @red;
}
```

But I want that, because the rest of the links on my site I still want this behavior...that it hovers with a black underline.  I just don't want it for my navigation links.  Not sure what to do..how to keep this and then disable that text-decoration in my Nav component.

Update

It was suggested that I move the styles to my  tag.  But when I do that then it underlines the entire

which is not what I want, I only want the text underlined.  So the underline is way too long when I move it to :

[image]

Comment: You want to remove black underline?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your class on the `<a>` instead of a child `<span>`:

```
<nav className="ink-navigation">
    <ul className="menu horizontal">
        <li><a href="#" className="grey-dark bold underline-grey">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: the reason I didn't do that is because then it borders way beyond the home text.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS inheritance rules, and define a more specific rule for the actual anchor element where you don't want the underline:

HTML:

```
<nav className="ink-navigation">
    <ul className="menu horizontal">
        <li><a id="homeAnchor" href="#"><span className="grey-dark bold underline-grey">Home</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (what I added):

```
#homeAnchor a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

Now your old rules will work the same everywhere.

Comment: isn't it bad to be using IDs in css.  I heard that's not the best practice to be doing these days...because you can end up with way too many styles going on when you start styling both based on id and classes

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here.  Your CSS defines a set of general rules, but this doesn't mean that there won't be exceptions to those rules.

Comment: "Bad to be using IDs in CSS"?  Engineering is about what works.  Some things are considered bad style, but IMHO adding tons of extra complexity to avoid "bad style" is worse -- worse for interoperability, worse for readability, and worse for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .horizontal a:hover {
            text-decoration:none;

          }
 .horizontal a:hover .underline-grey {
   
         border-bottom: 3px solid @red;
   
          }
```

Comment: No I want it to have a grey border...then when I hover turns red

Comment: and I don't want all my <a> on the site to have a red border either

Comment: a {
border-bottom: 3px solid @grey-xdark;
} is universal, I don't want that

Comment: I'm gonna have more elements in that <ul> for the nave and I'm even going to behaving other colors later on such as underline-brown, etc.

Comment: so is basically each of those inheriting downward?  In other words .underline-grey inherits from a:hover inherits from .horizontal? how is this workiing, that particular syntax?

Comment: it works but feels messy, anyone looking at my css is gonna be like wtf, why so many combinations here, just seems overkill to me

Comment: ok you pointed me in the right direction.  Here is what I came up with that's a bit cleaner.  I basically said kill hover on all nav elements, then apply my custom styles.  

.ink-navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.underline-grey {
  border-bottom: 3px solid @grey-xdark;
}

.underline-grey:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid @red;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
.ink-navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.underline-grey {
  border-bottom: 3px solid @grey-xdark;
}

.underline-grey:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid @red;
}
```

Comment: I really have to say WTF here (no pun intended).  You should upvote the answers which helped you and ideally mark one correct.